# Socket Programming with Broadcast Recevier

Tags: android, sockets, broadcastreceiver

I am developing Android application(online marketing), within this project i am using socket programming for communication with server, when i communicate with server if server does not give me any response within 30 sec then my **asynctask** will close automatically, but now problem is i want to save server response in **sqlite** on receiving response from server please provide me the necessary help thank
you in advance.

**Here is My Asyntask :**

```
public class SendToserver extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer>
{
    int iReturn;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressDialog(Registartion.this, "Please Wait...");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ServerData = runm(IMEINo);
        if (ServerData.equalsIgnoreCase("IsNull"))
        {
            iReturn = 2;
        }
        else {
            iReturn = 1;
        }

        return iReturn;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (iReturn == 1) 
        {
            String ServerIP = edtServerIpAddress.getText().toString();
            String ServerPort = edtServerPort.getText().toString();

            registartionModel = new RegistartionModel();
            registartionModel.setServerIPAdreess(ServerIP);
            registartionModel.setPort(ServerPort);

            registrationDb = new RegistrationDb(getApplicationContext());
            registrationDb.open();
            registrationDb.insertData(registartionModel);
            registrationDb.close();

            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            Registartion.this.finish();
            System.gc();

        }
        else if (iReturn == 2) 
        {
            showDialogBox("Please Input Correct Server IP and Port");
        }

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

My Server Communication Method(runm):

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public String runm(String DId) 
{
    try {
            socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVERPORT);
            out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out.write((DId + "|" +"REG").getBytes());
            ServerData = in.readLine();
            System.err.println("Server Data in Runm :- " + ServerData);

            if(ServerData == null || ServerData.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                ServerData="IsNull";
            }

    } 
    catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException e)
    {
        ServerData = "IsNull";
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        ServerData = "IsNull";
    }
    return ServerData;
}
```

Should i use Broadcast Receiver ?

Comment: Create service to perform long running task. You can update sqlite database from service and if you want to update activity then you can use broadcast receiver.

Comment: Can you please tell how to create service in asynctask?

Comment: Create Service as separate Task. To create service, you will get more info from (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).